# Extract exact match between two files using grep

Tags: file, grep, match

I am using the below line to extract the lines in the SourceFile which match the items in the ListFile.

```
grep -Ff ListFile SourceFile > output.txt
```

The ListFile file is in the below format. (One column, no header)

```
1:21314
2:43512
4:24312
...
...
...
```

The SourceFile is in the below format (Two columns, no header). Output.txt is subset of SourceFile.

```
1:5345     rs123
1:4525     rs345
1:53543    rs4523
1:21314    rs35235
1:213142   rs214523
```

The problem is my code also return similar match, not just exact match.

For example, 1:21314 is in the ListFile.

The output of my code will return both 1:21314 and 1:213142 of the SourceFile.

What should I add to only select exact match?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add option `-w` to your `grep` command.

From `man grep`:

> `-w`:
> Select  only those lines containing matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must either be at the beginning
> of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or followed  by  a  non-
> word  constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.